# Recover SanDisk SSD PLUS 480GB Internal SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm - SDSSDA-480G-G26

Tags: ssd, recovery

Accidentally formatted lost data my SanDisk SSD PLUS 480GB Internal SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm - SDSSDA-480G-G26 
so I need to recover los data my SanDisk SSD PLUS 480GB. any suggesion?

Comment: An SSD may still not be recoverable by any of these tools if the formatting tool used TRIM on the entire disk.

Comment: ohf , another way it possible?

Comment: Try the tools. If they find nothing, then all is lost.